# pandas convert object to time format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe time column with object datatype and would like to convert time format for graph.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time":["12:30:31.320"]
})
df["time"]
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['time'] # Output Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: There is no specific type for a collection of time records in Pandas. It's still `object` but that doesn't mean your individual values can't be a python instance of time

Answer (score 0):

To keep Python's `time` instance, you can use:

```
df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
                .dt.floor('S')  # remove milliseconds
                .dt.time)  # keep time part
```

Output:

```
>>> df['time']
0    12:30:31
Name: time, dtype: object  # the dtype is object but...

>>> df.loc[0, 'time']
datetime.time(12, 30, 31)  # ...contain a list of time objects
```

Comment: how can I use this time object to plot in x-axis as time.